# Trigger TreeView AfterSelect event multiple times

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I have a TreeView control. Say I have 5 nodes in it. On selecting a node, I populate a ListView with all the Directories under that SelectedNode. Then, I click a Button, which modifies the ListView Items.

So, when I select the Node in the TreeView again (the same one which I selected previously), the AfterSelect event is not firing. And because of this my ListView is not getting updated.

Any ideas guys/gals?

Comment: Expecting the user to discover that clicking a node that is already selected will have an effect is wishful thinking.  Add a Refresh button and implement the F5 keystroke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not possible.** The `AfterSelect` event will not be raised again, because the node that was selected is *already* selected. **The selection is not changing**, so the event will not be raised.

As Hans points out in a comment to the original question, it's very likely poor UI design to expect a user to realize that clicking again on a node that is already selected will have some sort of effect. The better solution is to add "Refresh" functionality to your application. This is generally mapped to the <kbd>F5</kbd> key, and/or the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keyboard shortcut.

If you absolutely must trigger some action when a node is *re-selected*, you will need to handle it at a lower level than the `AfterSelect` event. And that means figuring out which node the user clicked manually. To do that, handle the [`MouseDown` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown.aspx), and use the [`HitTest` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.hittest.aspx) to determine the node at the location the user clicked. It's not pretty, nor do I recommend it, but it will get the job done.

```
private void myTreeView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewHitTestInfo info = myTreeView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

    // Ensure that the user actually clicked on a node (there are lots of areas
    // over which they could potentially click that do not contain a node)
    if ((info.Node != null) && (info.Node == myTreeView.SelectedNode))
    {
        // The user clicked on the currently-selected node,
        // so refresh the TreeView
        // . . . 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this code was useful to me. Would you mind giving the code for same situation but when user navigates through UI with TAB key?

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to toggle the selected node...

```
    treeView.NodeMouseClick += delegate(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e) {
        TreeNode selected = e.Node;

        // If node already selected - unselect, then reselect
        if (selected == treeView.SelectedNode) {
            treeView.SelectedNode = null;
            treeView.SelectedNode = selected;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not firing because the item is already selected. Handle the `MouseDown` or `PreviewMouseDown` instead.

Comment: I know. Isnt there any other way, i could do so in the AfterSelect event only ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MouseClick event instead of the AfterSelect event:

```
Sub treeView1_NodeMouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.NodeMouseClick

    ' textBox1.Text = e.Node.Text
    If Not e.Node.Tag Is Nothing Then
        Dim frm As Form = DirectCast(e.Node.Tag, Form)
        frm.ShowDialog()
        ''frm.Dispose()

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

@Cody Gray Even this is a very all post, just like to post and answer.
I think if you Collapse & Expand the treeview in the same time you select node it will work. codes as below

```
MyTreeview.CollapseAll()
MyTreeview.ExpandAll()
```

Comment: Aside from the hackish nature of this approach, it makes for terrible UX on multiple levels. First, there’s the inevitable flicker/flash as the UI rapidly changes. Second, it loses user state. How I leave the TreeView expanded/collapsed is my decision; an app should persist that, not throw it away pointlessly.